# How to resolve RecaptchaError from Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, recaptcha

I am trying to add reCAPTCHA in my site but i got the following error when i tried to open the registration page.

Error:

```
Recaptcha::RecaptchaError in Users#new

Showing C:/Site/recaptcha/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #27 raised:

No public key specified.
```

Please check my following codes and help me to resolve this error.

## config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = '6LfPjAQTAAAAAHIcZm6r***************'
  config.private_key = '6LfPjAQTAAAAALfyn4pu***************'
end
```

## views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h3>New User Sign Up</h3>
<% if !@user.errors.empty? %>
  <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
<div>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Actually the error is showing at this line  "<%= recaptcha_tags %>".Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: @user4703663 I am using gem 'recaptcha', '~> 0.3.5'

Comment: Can anybody solve this issue..?

Answer (score 2):

Just updated my rails app with version 4.0.0 of this [recaptcha gem](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) and found that the environmental variable names changed.

From:

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY']  = '6LfPjAQTAAAAAHIcZm6r***************'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = '6LfPjAQTAAAAALfyn4pu***************'
```

To:

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY']   = '6LfPjAQTAAAAAHIcZm6r***************'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'] = '6LfPjAQTAAAAALfyn4pu***************'
```

Upon updating my [application.yml](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) file Recaptcha was back to working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your environment.rb file:

```
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY']  = '6LfPjAQTAAAAAHIcZm6r***************'
ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = '6LfPjAQTAAAAALfyn4pu***************'
```

then restart server.